# WF4.5 Statemachine: Grand Parent State to close or finalize the wf instance

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Is there a way to give contorl to a state where it can close/Finish the workflow instance irrespective of it's current state.

Here is the scenario.

```
Start -> Approver_1 -> Approver_2 -> Final
```

Step 1) A request is created and is available on Approver_1.
Step 2) Approver_1 has approved it to push the request to Approver_2.
Step 3.a) Approver_2 can approve it to finalize the request. .
but......
Step 3.b) Approver_1 felt he is not in need of request he wanted to reject/close the request.

How is that we can achive this using State machine WF4.5

Note: the sample flow I over simplified :)

Answer (score 1):

So you need to finish workflow from inside state entry/exit action? I don't know any interresting wat to do this. May be you can use TerminateWorkflow with given string reason, but I seems strange to do such approval process. May be I don't understand question.

Better way to solve approval process is to have each state is assigned to one approver, so after start, WF goes to Approve1 state and needs approval from Approver1. You can create transition to Final from this state, if first approve denied approval. Another transition for approve action goes to Approve2 state and needs approval from Approver2. He also 2 posibilities: one transition to approve and another to deny.